# Should you plug a laser printer directly into a wall socket?

Tags: laser-printer, surge-protection

Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/466642/why-shouldnt-i-attach-laser-printers-or-scanners-to-a-ups/466645#466645) to the question ["Why shouldn't I attach laser printers or scanners to a UPS?"](https://superuser.com/questions/466642/why-shouldnt-i-attach-laser-printers-or-scanners-to-a-ups), and a [comment made by Blunder](https://superuser.com/questions/466642/why-shouldnt-i-attach-laser-printers-or-scanners-to-a-ups#comment549008_466645), should you plug a printer directly into a wall socket and avoid plugging it into a surge protector?

> When turned on, Laser printers draw a very high current to heat up their fuser roller. their current draw can go from 0 to 20A in milliseconds. A typical UPS cannot cope with such a spike.
>
> The problem is this inrush current at start-up, not the normal operating current. The inrush current can be seven times the normal operating current of the printer.

As a surge protector aims to limit sudden spikes in voltage, it would seem that a surge protector would restrict this inrush current, as increased current would cause a higher potential difference in voltage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surge protectors are designed to protect the equipment from voltage surges in the supply, typically they block or divert the supply at voltages over 3xnominal (e.g. at 330V on a normally 110V supply).

The typical threat is a lightning strike on the power line nearby. "An average bolt of negative lightning carries an electric current of about 30,000 to 100,000 amperes (30-100 kA) at a voltage of over a billion volts." ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning)) Of course this is much reduced by the time any voltage surge reaches your surge protector but this is the type of event for which surge protectors were intended.

A Laser printer, or other device, drawing a very high current (20-40 A) for 10-20 mS will not cause a voltage RISE in the supply, it is more likely to cause a short-duration voltage DROP in the supply (e.g. from 110 V AC to 90 V AC)

Comment: +1, completely neglected to think about how potential differences actually work in regards to the power supply.

Answer (score 0):

Check any printer manufacturers site and you will find that they all say to never plug a laser printer into a surge protector or extension cord. Either one can cause a voltage drop which can damage the printer components.

Comment: Can you quote some sites?